# has() function on empty ErrorBag returns different boolean result depending on environment

Tags: laravel, error-handling, laravel-5

In laravel app, I have a discrepancy on the output of the following line:

```
$errors->has();
```

depending on the environment; it returns `false` locally, `true` on stage and prod.

I dumped the defined vars and get the same empty array in both:

```
"errors" => ViewErrorBag {#170 ▼
  #bags: []
}
```

I `$errors->count();` which returns `0` in both envs.

What could be the reason?

Comment: The `ViewErrorBag` uses `Illuminate\Support\Collection` which provides the `->has()` method which returns `array_key_exists($key, $this->items)`. So unless `array_key_exists` shows the same error  `array_key_exists('', $errors->toArray())` then there's something else going on.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy `array_key_exists` returns false on all envs

Comment: Please navigate to `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php`. Go to around line `1173` where the `offsetExists` function is located. `dd($key)` here. What do you see?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy from the blade view, it doesn't trigger the `dd`